# Receiving data from arduino via serial in C # application

Tags: c#, arduino, serial-port

I need to make an application that sends and receives data from an arduino leonardo. I tried some examples of serial connection between C # and Arduino and in all cases I had the same problem, the arduino receives the data sent by the application but the application does not receive the data sent by the Arduino. I tested with COM emulator and it worked perfectly, but with arduino it does not work.

Here are the codes used.

Application C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2 {
public partial class Form1 : Form {

    string RxString;
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        serialPort1.DataReceived += serialPort1_DataReceived;
        timerCOM.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void atualizaListaCOMs() {
        int i;
        bool quantDiferente; //flag para sinalizar que a quantidade de portas mudou

        i = 0;
        quantDiferente = false;

        //se a quantidade de portas mudou
        if (comboBox1.Items.Count == SerialPort.GetPortNames().Length) {
            foreach (string s in SerialPort.GetPortNames()) {
                if (comboBox1.Items[i++].Equals(s) == false) {
                    quantDiferente = true;
                }
            }
        } else {
            quantDiferente = true;
        }

        //Se não foi detectado diferença
        if (quantDiferente == false) {
            return;                     //retorna
        }

        //limpa comboBox
        comboBox1.Items.Clear();

        //adiciona todas as COM diponíveis na lista
        foreach (string s in SerialPort.GetPortNames()) {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(s);
        }
        //seleciona a primeira posição da lista
        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }

    private void timerCOM_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        atualizaListaCOMs();
    }

    private void btConectar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (serialPort1.IsOpen == false) {
            try {
                serialPort1.PortName = comboBox1.Items[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].ToString();
                serialPort1.Open();

            } catch {
                return;

            }
            if (serialPort1.IsOpen) {
                btConectar.Text = "Desconectar";
                comboBox1.Enabled = false;

            }
        } else {

            try {
                serialPort1.Close();
                comboBox1.Enabled = true;
                btConectar.Text = "Conectar";
            } catch {
                return;
            }

        }
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e) {
        if (serialPort1.IsOpen == true)  // se porta aberta
            serialPort1.Close();         //fecha a porta
    }

    private void btEnviar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (serialPort1.IsOpen == true)          //porta está aberta
            serialPort1.Write(textBoxEnviar.Text);  //envia o texto presente no textbox Enviar
    }

    private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) {
        RxString = serialPort1.ReadExisting();              //le o dado disponível na serial
        this.Invoke(new EventHandler(trataDadoRecebido));   //chama outra thread para escrever o dado no text box
    }

    private void trataDadoRecebido(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        textBoxReceber.AppendText(RxString);
    }
    }
}
```

Arduino:

```
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);  //inicia comunicação serial com 9600
}

void loop()
{
  if(Serial.available())        //se algum dado disponível
  {
    char c = Serial.read();   //le o byte disponivel
    delay(500);
    Serial.write(c);           //retorna o que foi lido
  }
}
```

Comment: serialPort1_DataReceived() event you either need to register the event in port properties or in the code use "+="

Comment: This was already set in the event panel on the design screen.

Comment: why the delay in Arduino?

Comment: A test only, without the delay also does not work

Answer (score 0):

I like to use Thread and a loop to read serial data.
In your case you must register your event like:

```
serialPort1.DataReceived +=serialPort1_DataReceived;
```

and the open it

```
serialPort1.Open();
```

As a result the evet will fire whenever data received.

Comment: This was already set in the event panel on the design screen. I tried to use threads, but it did not work either.

Comment: @Dan Pimentel therefor there should not be any software problem, Other assumption meight be the difference between baudrate, or difference between voltage level, to make sure connect pc side gnd to leonardo gnd.

Comment: On the other sidr you can first validate your leonardo side code by Ardiono IDE serial port terminal. After making sure about leonardo then work on c# sidr

Comment: I tested both arduino and c # in putty and another COM port emulator, and both worked.

Comment: @DanPimentel if you are sure about Arduino side, Parity, Stopbit, RTS and other property of the serial port, the use [this open source c# app](http://andreiprojects.blogspot.com/2011/09/c-serial-port-terminal.html) to find the problem. As far as I can see, there is not any problem in your c# code.